# Map-Reduce combiner does not work

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, combiners

I have tried to use this script:
http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~dsp112/Map-Reduce_Template
But the Combiner fails at (line 69).

Combine output records  11,746,934
...
Combine input records   11,746,934

I have analysed the text flat file, but how I can debug it?

Comment: DOes the reducer also show a similar number of input and output values - it might just be that every key output from your map stage is unique - hence no combination or reduction. What does the output key/values look like, are they what you are expecting?